# Separating by columns in read_bulk()

Tags: r, csv, merge

I'm using the `readbulk` package to read 40 csv files and merge them. All of the input csv files have 21 columns, however when I inspect the outputs, there are only four columns. I notice that the columns are all together, separated by a period. I don't see an option to manage the columns in the output in the `read_bulk()` function. What can I do differently?

My code:

```
library(readbulk)
input_path<- "/Volumes/WININSTALL/Filename_Redux/Zone1_Output/"

file_list<- list.files(input_path, pattern = "[.]csv$")

file_paste<- paste(input_path, file_list, sep = "")

merged<- read_bulk(directory = input_path, subdirectories = FALSE, extension = ".csv")
```

Comment: You could try using a different library: `library(tidyverse); file_paste %>% purrr::map_dfr(read.csv)`

Comment: Why not start with base R? `df_list <- lapply(file_list, read.csv)` and go from there.

Comment: Thank you both for your advice. Mako212's suggestion still results in the same issue... Rui Barradas's suggestion gives me a list without columns.

Comment: I'd recommend checking two things: 1) Are your .csv files properly formatted - can you read a single file correctly 2) Check that column names are consistent across files, you'll have to handle any inconsistency before condensing things into a single data frame.

Comment: Start with something like `read.csv(file_paste[1])`. Review the result, and make sure it looks correct.